# Vuetify app bar overflow hidden not working

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Overflow hidden not working. It creates another scroll bar like in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ygGT.png)

I copied the code directly from [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars/#examples) and tried it in [code pen](https://codepen.io/kengowada/pen/MWabZQE?editable=true&editors=101) and the results were the same.

```html
<template>
  <v-card class="overflow-hidden">
    <v-app-bar
      absolute
      color="#fcb69f"
      dark
      shrink-on-scroll
      src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random"
      scroll-target="#scrolling-techniques-2"
    >
      <template v-slot:img="{ props }">
        <v-img
          v-bind="props"
          gradient="to top right, rgba(19,84,122,.5), rgba(128,208,199,.8)"
        ></v-img>
      </template>

      <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

      <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
      </v-btn>`enter code here`
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-sheet
      id="scrolling-techniques-2"
      class="overflow-y-auto"
      max-height="600"
    >
      <v-container style="height: 1000px;"></v-container>
    </v-sheet>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Comment: What effect/part do you want to hide exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `overflow-hidden` class from the `v-card` that wraps the `v-app-bar` and `v-sheet`. (You might just remove the `v-card` altogether)

I would guess the vuetify docs have this so the examples work on their own site.

Answer (score 0):

> This is happening for two reasons-

1. **Outer Scrollbar comes from html.**

   - bcz your contents like- v-sheet, v-container exceed your screen height
2. **Inner Scrollbar is for v-sheet**

   - bcz v-sheet's max-height is 600px & It's content container's height is 1000px which overflows v-sheet's height.

> There is no fixed height of v-card, it's flexible to it's content. So,
>   don't add overflow-hidden class to it. You should hidden in any of
>   `html` or `v-sheet`